# How to navigate to a previous line in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, alias

I have a bash script with a lot of if/elif statements.

Is there a way to take the output of a command, and make it execute the associated if/elif statement, rather than the default version of the command?

For example, in the main script, I have the following:

```bash
if [ "$command" == "ls" ]
then
    ls -la
elif # ...(hundreds more if/elif statements here) ...

fi
```

If I execute:

`echo "ls" >> tempcommand; bash tempcommand`

within my script, is it possible to pipe the `ls` command from that execution through the above specified if statement from the main script?

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete script and it's intended usage so we know what you really mean by the terminology you're using as it's not clear what `if/elif functions, as opposed to function() aliases` means as `if/elif statements`, `functions`, and `aliases` are 3 completely different things and if you have `if/elif statements` instead of `functions` or `aliases` then it's not clear what you'd mean by calling them elsewhere in your script. It's also not clear if whatever it is should ONLY be called in the script within which it's defined or outside of it too.

Comment: It's also not clear what `take the output of a command, and make it execute the alias of a command in my script` means.

Comment: Aliases are only used in an **interactive** bash shell. `bash tempcommand` is not interactive. You can force it to be: `bash -i tempcommand`

Comment: "If I execute ... within my script, is it possible to pipe the ls command from that execution through the above specified if statement from the main script?" -- only if the cascading if statements are stored in a function. You'll have to give us more context about your script.

Comment: But to address the gist of your question, shell does not have `goto`, so you'll have to refactor your program into functions. Shell functions are the only "addressable" units of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case as you:

my `ls` implementation:

```
$ cat ~/bin/ls
#!/bin/bash

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/sid-chroot/usr /path/sid-chroot/bin/ls "$@"
```

```
$ ls --version 
ls (GNU coreutils) 9.1
```

```
$ /bin/ls --version 
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.32
```

And I have an alias:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto -F'
```

All works as expected.

You need to put your implementation of `ls` early in the `PATH` environment variable.

So in your case, you need to add to `tempcommand` the `PATH` variable with the directory of your `ls` and `alias` definition. Maybe, the most simple is to add :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

to your script.